# How to create fxcop rule to check that a class call init in its constructor on another class?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, fxcop

Let's say I have class A which instantiates class B. class B has a constructor and several init methods (enforced through a class interface). How to write fxcop rule to check that at least one init method is called after instantiating B.

What if you load it at runtime from internet you cannot use constructor so the init.

Comment: How about correcting the design error instead? An object should be ready for use when constructed

Comment: What if you load it at runtime from internet you cannot use constructor !

Comment: @user310291: please, by curiosity, can you provide a sample code where you can actually use an object without being able to constructing it?

Comment: @Rune FS: that's a cheap answer to give.  Ideally, you'd want to be able to have all initialization happen through the constructor.  But sometimes, initialization must be deferred due to the way the objects must interact with other code.

Comment: @siride or you wait with the construction till you have all the needed information. And I didn't write constructor but construction you might want to use an initilizer but if that's _required_ wrap the call to the constructor and initializer up in a factory method.

Comment: @user310291 what stops you from loading the needed information before constructing the object or to wrap the deserialization up in a method?

Answer (score 1):

This sort of rule is nearly impossible to write except for the most trivial cases.  For example, if you want to ensure that a B init method is called immediately after invoking a B constructor, that can be done relatively easily (although branching logic can cause problems even there).  However, there wouldn't be much need for a separate init method if one only needed to support such trivial usage.  What is generally more interesting to detect are cases where one attempts to do something else with a B instance before invoking its init method, and that's not really a job for a static verifier like FxCop.

Have you considered throwing an exception from B if it is not initialized at entry into another method (much like one might throw an ObjectDisposedException from a disposed instance)?